# jQuery.removeCookie Wordpress Plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a website based on Wordpress. I'm using onetone template and I would like to setup popups on my website.
So I've downloaded Popup Builder.

When I try to set a popup, I'm having an error message in Console :

> jQuery.removeCookie is not a function

But cookie plugin is installed into Popup Builder folder.

What should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am using wordpress 4.6 and Popup Builder 2.3.9.1, it is working fine on my system without any error.

Can you please elaborate more.

Comment: Question asked 5 months ago, a fresh install resolved the issue. Thanks :)